# Incorrect return value from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

The `ajax` call snipet below returns either 'found' or 'no' as a `string` from the server. The first line of the `callback` `alert(d)` shows the result returned. However, the line `if (d == "found")` is never true, even when 'found' is returned. Please what am I missing? Thanks for the help.

```
$.get('includes/reg_fns.php', {
    'op': 'availability',
    'field': $(this).attr('name'),
    'val': val
}, function(d) {
    alert(d);
    if (d == "found") {
        alert("<br /><span style='font-size:83%;color:red; margin-left:117px'>&nbsp;[ <b>*</b> " + val + " is already taken.</span><br />");
    } else {
        alert('false here');
    }
});​
```

Comment: `console.log(d, d == "found");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you are returning with extra space on it.

try using trim() on it.

```
if( d.trim()=='found')
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
($.trim(d) == "found")
```

instead of

```
if (d == "found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use simple d. You have to use d.d.
 Try this

```
alert(d.d);
    if (d.d == "found") {
        alert("<br /><span style='font-size:83%;color:red; margin-left:117px'>&nbsp;[ <b>*</b> " + val + " is already taken.</span><br />");
    } else {
        alert('false here');
    }
```